# How to set DPI in Barcode image by using BarcodeLib Library

Tags: c#, windows, barcode, barcode-printing

I am using BarcodeLib for generate barcode label but when print to thermal printer this label not properly set cause of DPI. Now how can i set DPI Using BarcodeLib library

now i want to set DPI when generate barcode label, or how can i create barcode label with DPI with free library

Comment: Please show your code. Is this about C# and .NET? What do you mean by "this label not properly set"? Show or describe what it looks like and what you expect instead.

Comment: I am using c# Windows form following reference https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib

Comment: It's still unclear how you print the barcode and what the result looks like.

Comment: From your question you are most likely using a thermal printer (desktop) using the Zebra ZPL print language.   Notice that in printers, *what* you print is unrelated to the printer settings (DPI). It can be a barcode, or a simple "Hello World". Did you in fact study [a previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246576/how-to-change-the-dpi-from-200-to-300-through-zpl) and [official documentation](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/zpl-command-information-and-details.html) ?

Comment: Actually, I want to print barcode label to Zebra ZT230 203 Dpi Thermal Printer Using C# desktop application (printDocument tools).
i have already created barcode generator using c# winForm using Library is BarcodeLib.(Reference : github.com/barnhill/barcodelib) . but here barcode image does not fit the specified paper size in barcode printer (tharmal printer)